# Qt - is there a way to transform a graphic item into a pixmap?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem

I want to create a pixmap from a graphicObject, so i can set the pixmap as an icon

I have a `Block` class derived from `QGraphicsPathItem` and i tried using:

```
Block *block = new Block();

QRect rect = block->boundingRect().toRect();

QPixmap pixmapItem;
pixmapItem.copy(rect);

QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem;
item->setIcon(QPixmap(pixmapItem));
```

but the pixmap appears to be empty.

Is there a way to get an image/icon out of a graphicObject or graphicItem?

Comment: As far as I can see, the only thing that you are doing with block is getting its bounding rect and then getting a subset of pixmapItem (which is empty) using that rect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the [`paint()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) method of `QGraphicsItem` to get the rendering:

```
static QPixmap QPixmapFromItem(QGraphicsItem *item){
    QPixmap pixmap(item->boundingRect().size().toSize());
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt;
    item->paint(&painter, &opt);
    return pixmap;
}
```

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsPathItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QListWidget>

static QPixmap QPixmapFromItem(QGraphicsItem *item){
    QPixmap pixmap(item->boundingRect().size().toSize());
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt;
    item->paint(&painter, &opt);
    return pixmap;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QHBoxLayout lay(&w);
    QListWidget listWidget;
    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    view.setScene(&scene);

    int counter = 0;
    for(const QColor & color : {QColor("red"), QColor("blue"), QColor("green")}){
        QPainterPath p;
        p.addRoundedRect(0, 0, 150, 50, 2, 2);
        QGraphicsPathItem *block = scene.addPath(p);
        block->setBrush(QBrush(color));
        block->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
        block->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
        block->setPos(counter*QPointF(10, 10));

        // get QPixmap from item
        QPixmap pixmap = QPixmapFromItem(block); 

        QListWidgetItem *l_item = new QListWidgetItem(color.name());
        listWidget.addItem(l_item);
        l_item->setIcon(QIcon(pixmap));
        counter++;
    }
    lay.addWidget(&listWidget);
    lay.addWidget(&view);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `painter.end()` is unnecessary, since it's a RAII class that "self-closes" just like `QFile` etc.

Comment: The passing of the pixmaps to list widget data is very nice!

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, I know, I forgot to delete it, thanks for letting me know. :D

Comment: If your GraphicsItem does not have its top-left corner at (0,0), you may want to add `painter.translate(-item->boundingRect().x(),-item->boundingRect().y());` to offset the painter, and to avoid cropping the image

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to use `QGraphicsItem::paint` for this:

```
QSize itemSize = item->boundingRect()
QPixmap targetPixmap(item->boundingRect().size().toSize());

QPainter pixmapPainter(&targetPixmap);
QStyleOptionGraphicsItem styleOption;
item->paint(&pixmapPainter, &styleOption);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because a bounding rectangle only contains coordinate and size information about your QGraphicsItem but no further information about how to draw it.

You could try something similar to the following: Create a `QImage` of your `block`'s size and use it to initialize a `QPainter`. The `QPainter` can then be used by the `block` to draw on the image. This is achieved using the `paint` method which `Block` inherits from `QGraphicsItem`

```
Block *block = new Block();
QSize size = block->boundingRect().toRect().toSize();
QImage* image = new QImage(size, QImage::Format_RGB32);
QPainter* painter = new QPainter(image);
block->paint(painter, new StyleOptionGraphicsItem());
```

Then your `block` should have be painted to `image`.

Comment: At least `painter` and `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem` should be automatic variables here - your code leaks memory otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the nice example by [@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc). In addition a translate command also mandatory in some cases.

```
 static QPixmap QPixmapFromItem(QGraphicsItem *item){
            QPixmap pixmap(item->boundingRect().size().toSize());
            pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
            QPainter painter(&pixmap);
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
            QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt;
            painter.translate (-1 * (item->boundingRect ().topLeft ()));//THIS IS MANDATORY IN SOME CASES.
            item->paint(&painter, &opt);
            return pixmap;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is long time ago and solved, I just want to contribute the "translation" of the function in Python and PyQt5:

```python
    def convert( self, item: QGraphicsItem ):
        pixmap = QPixmap( item.boundingRect().size().toSize() )
        pixmap.fill( Qt.transparent )
        painter = QPainter( pixmap )
        # this line seems to be needed for all items except of a LineItem...
        painter.translate( -item.boundingRect().x(), -item.boundingRect().y())
        painter.setRenderHint( QPainter.Antialiasing, True )
        opt = QStyleOptionGraphicsItem()
        item.paint( painter, opt , self) # here in some cases the self is needed
        return pixmap


# The "some cases": Placing this function in a QGraphicsScene-Subclass was ok without the "self", but placing it in QWidget-Subclass needed this self.
```

Thanks for all answers here :-)

...but I have to admit, that I don't really understand what is happening in the line `item.paint( painter, opt , self)`
I would be happy about any explanation how this works, but I am also happy that it works ;-)